# Traduction de « 23-year-old self »

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs, pronoms-réfléchis

Quelqu'un pourrait-il me traduire correctement ou fournir un équivalent en français des expressions anglaises « 23-year-old self » et « younger-self » ?

Comment la phrase suivante devrait-elle être traduite ?

> I write a letter to my 23-year-old self.

Comment: `younger-self` (avec un "n") plutôt ? Sans contexte, il peut y avoir plusieurs traductions possible, car qu'on ait 15 ou 30 ans, `23-year-old self` sera traduit différemment.

Comment: Oui, je cherche une correspondance en français de ces expressions qui paraissent simples d'usage en anglais.

Comment: Quand je n'avais que 23 ans ? Compliqué de traduire cette tournure de phrase... Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une expression équivalente en français.

Comment: « À mon futur moi de 23 ans » could be a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could translate it by "J'écris une lettre à mon moi d'antan." (My younger self) or "Je m'écris une lettre pour quand j'avais 23 ans." / "J'écris une lettre à mon moi de 23 ans".

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to have a full English sentence using that expression but *moi à vingt-trois ans* and *moi plus jeune* might be proper translations.

Comment: "I write a letter to my 23-year-old self"

Comment: *Je m'écris une lettre, adressée à mon moi de vingt-trois ans* ( http://leplus.nouvelobs.com/contribution/205760-lettre-a-moi-a-20-ans.html )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any canonical direct translation, usually the sentence is reformulated to avoid having to say that.

However the slang "mon moi du passé" can be sometimes heard.

Answer (score 0):

Pour une projection future :

> Lettre de ma main que je lirai le jour de mes futurs vingt-trois.

Pour les souvenirs :

> Lettre de ma main pour les souvenirs de ma vingt-troisième année.